# sql execute block error: multiple rows in singleton select

Tags: sql, firebird

I am struggling to make the code bellow to work. Whenever I try it gives me the error `multiple rows in singleton select`

```
execute block returns (order integer,sales decimal(18,2))
as
declare variable client varchar(10);

begin

for

select clientcode from clients

into  :client

do
begin

select order_id, sum(amount)sales from orders where order_date='today' and clientcode= :client
group by 1

into :order,:sales;

suspend;
end
end
```

the error

```
Error in result_fetch(res@ptr, n) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:2593: HY000: [ODBC Firebird Driver][Firebird]multiple rows in singleton select
```

If I change the second select, it returns a set, but only the first occurrence.

```
select first(1) order_id, sum(amount)sales from orders where order_date='today' and clientcode= :client
group by 1
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `select` in PSQL, then it must produce at most one row. Given the error, the query is producing more than one row.

If you need to produce multiple rows, then you have to use [`for select ... do`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-forselect), for example:

```
execute block returns (order integer,sales decimal(18,2))
as
declare variable client varchar(10);
begin
  for select clientcode 
    from clients
    into :client 
    do
  begin
    for select order_id, sum(amount)sales 
      from orders 
      where order_date='today' and clientcode= :client
      group by 1
      into :order,:sales
      do
    begin
      suspend;
    end
  end
end
```

Be aware, that this code would be better written as an `inner join`.

```
select o.order_id, sum(o.amount) as sales
from client c
inner join orders o
  on o.clientcode = c.clientcode
group by c.clientcode, o.order_id
```

Comment: Hi Mark. It worked.I could indeed use the inner join to solve this problem but this is just a simplification of my real problem. The real problem I had to solve is much more complex, using CTE´s etc, so I needed to learn and use execute block on this case. Anyway, your help was amazing.  Thanks a lot !